# Excel VBA: Selected = True causing 'Object doesn't support this property or method' error when trying to select multiple slicer values

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I was trying to select multiple values in a slicer with Excel VBA by the following code that I found in my search

```
Sub ApplyMultipleSlicerValues()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim slicer As Slicer
    Dim slicerCache As SlicerCache
    Dim selectedValues() As Variant
    Dim value As Variant
    
    ' Set the workbook and worksheet references
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your actual sheet name
    
    ' Set the slicer cache reference
    Set slicerCache = wb.SlicerCaches("Slicer1") ' Replace "Slicer1" with your actual slicer name
    
    ' Define the values to apply to the slicer
    selectedValues = Array("Value1", "Value2", "Value3") ' Replace with your desired values
    
    ' Clear all selections in the slicer
    slicerCache.ClearAllFilters
    
    ' Loop through each value and select it in the slicer
    For Each value In selectedValues
        For Each slicer In slicerCache.Slicers
            slicer.SlicerItems(value).Selected = True --> ERROR
        Next slicer
    Next value
    
    ' Refresh the worksheet to apply the slicer filter
    ws.RefreshAll
    
    ' Clear slicer selection
    For Each slicer In slicerCache.Slicers
        slicer.ClearManualFilter
    Next slicer
End Sub
```

Excel generated error

> '438' - Object doesn't support this property or method

at the line `Selected = True` above. I am not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A [`Slicer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.slicer) has no `SlicerItems` property.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to select/unselect by an array of values:

```vb
    ' Loop through each value and select/unselect it in the slicer
    Dim si As SlicerItem
    For Each si In slicerCache.VisibleSlicerItems
        If UBound(Filter(selectedValues, si.Name)) >= 0 Then
            si.Selected = True
        Else
            si.Selected = False
        End If
    Next
```

You have to check each `SlicerItem`  and set it to selected or not selected. `SlicerItem` is a property of `SlicerCache` - not `Slicer`.

Regarding the reason for your error: s. @BigBen s comment.
Same is true for `ClearManualFilter` which also applies to SlicerCache.

But it doesn't make sense here because it resets your selection ...

Comment: Hi Ike @Ike, I tried to use your code but it still says error 1004 at line For Each si. Do you have any idea why? This is what I actually currently have for slicerCache: slicerCache = wb.slicerCaches("Slicer_Policy_Prefix1"). The name Slicer_Policy_Prefix1 I got from the Slicer itself (Slicer Settings -> Name to use in formula). Is that the right way? Sorry for all the follow up questions please be patient with me I'm new to this VBA with slicers thingy.

Comment: You have to use **Set**: write `Set slicerCache = wb.slicerCaches("Slicer_Policy_Prefix1")`

Comment: yes @Ike I certainly did! I set it as the way it is in the code of my original code. It still prompts me with the error.